# How to obtain the read receipt and store inside a string?

Tags: asp.net, sendmail

In my project i have created a site from where my users or clients can send some documents to other users.

I also want to see if the recepient has read the mail/has the mail been sent.

Now i want to store the value of the result ie either "Sent" in case the mail has been successfully delivered. And "Viewed" when the mail has been opnened or read by the recepient.

I have done this code

```
MailMessage mailme = new MailMessage();
mailme.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
```

As i said above i want to store the value "Sent" or "Viewed" inside a string. Further ill store the values inside my tables.

How do i get the desired result. Basically i need to get the delivery report and report if the mail has been viewed.

Also i want to get the date as well as time when the mail was viewed by the recepient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
mailme.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "yourmail@mail.com");
```

where `"yourmail@mail.com"` should get a mail if the mail was read.

Comment: HI Daniel, as i said, i have to store the result in the database. Im not sure how to derive the value from my mail and store it in the database.

Comment: So question would be **how to store data in a database**? You already know how to access the notification mail?